# Where can I find Angular Materials' CSS directives?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I'm working with https://material.angularjs.org/latest/ with some components in a searcher.

I have a **md-datepicker** field and I want to apply some custom rules on it (background-color: white, custom size, etc).

https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker

And I need, for instance, to remove the arrow selector and the image (just applying some 'display:none').

I've tried to research on the official documentation in their repository, but it seems that what i was looking for is not there.

Comment: What exactly you want to find?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions asking us to suggest, find or recommend a book, tool, software library, plug-in, tutorial, explain a technique or provide any other **off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
.md-datepicker-triangle-button {
    display: none;
}
```